# Question regarding Python HTTP GET request using sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http, networking

Was wondering why I am getting a 408 request timeout when sending an HTTP GET request using sockets. I just copied the GET request that was sent through Chrome and then pasted it into python figuring that I would get a 200 response, but clearly, I am missing something.

```
 def GET():
    headers = ("""GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: {insert host here}\r
Connection: close\r
Cache-Control: max-age=0\r
DNT: 1\r
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36\r
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r
Cookie: accept_cookies=1\r\n""").encode('ascii')
payload = headers
return payload

def activity1():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    user = GET()
    sock.sendall(user)
    poop = sock.recv(10000)
    print(poop)
    sock.close()
```

Assuming the hostname and port are defined correctly is there anything wrong with this request that would cause it to timeout? Thanks.

Comment: why do you use `{insert host here}` ? You should put correct address. Server may have one IP adddress but it may serve many URLs/domains and it needs `Host: www.domain.com` to recognize which URL you want to get.

Comment: some servers expect `\r\n` after every line - not `\r` - and all servers expect two `\r\n` at the end - to create empty line at the end - it informs server that it is end of header. You have to learn HTTP first.

Comment: currenty many servers use secure connection HTTPS (instead of HTTP) and it needs something more then only headers. First it needs to use SSL to create seucure connection. Changing port from 80 to 443 is not enough

Comment: I use {insert host here} because the host is a web server hosted by my university and I don't want to potentially give away where I am from. Also, thank you it was the two \r\n's at the end. I didn't realize that was necessary at the end. The triple quotation marks keep the formatting so every line has a \n at the end even though it isn't written

Comment: @pizzahead911 Is there a reason why you are not simply using Python's own built-in HTTP client (via [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) or [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)), or a higher level client like the [Requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)? You really should not be handling the details of HTTP/S manually.

Comment: I agree. In a practical environment I would just use the requests library, but unfortunately the lab specifically says not to. I think it's stupid as well. I worked out the kinks in it, just took me a while and a lot of looking into what each of the lines being sent actually meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem is that the HTTP header is not properly finished, i.e. it is missing the final `\r\n` (empty line). Once this is done you will likely run into multiple other problems, like:

- You are assuming that everything can be read within a single `recv`, which will only be true for short answers.
- You likely assume that the body is a single byte buffer. But it can be transferred in chunks since HTTP/1.1 support this Transfer-Encoding.
- You likely assume that the body is in plain. But it can be compressed since you explicitly accept gzip-compressed responses.

HTTP is not the simple protocol as it might look. Please read the actual standard before implementing it, see [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230). Or just use a library which does the hard work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I read up a bit on the http protocol to understand a bit to understand what it was I was actually sending. In the case of this particular lab, a single recv is enough as the answers are simple. Like you said that probably wouldn't work in a practical environment, but I would also just use the requests library if I had my way. I figured out about the Accept-Encoding line yesterday. If you need to do what I did, don't include that line unless you want to be very confused when the content is in gzip.